# Blender Mapping Strand/Particle in v2.76

Tags: texturing

I was watching a tutorial and it came to mapping texture onto particle system. And under texture/Mapping/Cordinates: choose the Strand/Particle setting. But Blender 2.76 dosen't have that option. Is it somewhere else? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is located in the *textures* panel under *mapping>coordinates>strand/particle*[image]